# Pentaho kettle integration with Java

Tags: java, excel, pentaho, kettle

Here I am trying execute a transformation from Java. The java code is:

```
public class PDI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            KettleEnvironment.init();
            System.out.println("1");
            //StepLoader.init();
            EnvUtil.environmentInit();
            System.out.println("2");
            TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta("D:/pdi/external/ExcelSheet/person.ktr");
            System.out.println("3");
           Trans trans = new Trans( metaData );
           System.out.println("4");
           trans.execute(null);
           System.out.println("5");
          trans.waitUntilFinished();
          System.out.println("6");
            if ( trans.getErrors() > 0 ) {
                System.out.print( "Error Executing transformation" );
            }

        } catch (KettleException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

    }
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
1
2
3
4
2018/10/05 21:04:31 - person - Dispatching started for transformation [person]
5
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.poi.PoiCell.getType(PoiCell.java:43)child index = 0, logging object : org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject@5789a7e2 parent=718e171d-3be6-4174-a9d0-7ce8c54b2fb3
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)

    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.fillRow(ExcelInput.java:138)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.getRowFromWorkbooks(ExcelInput.java:665)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.processRow(ExcelInput.java:471)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.0.1.19046, build 1 from 2013-09-11_13-51-13 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.0.1.19046, build 1 from 2013-09-11_13-51-13 by buildguy) : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.poi.PoiCell.getType(PoiCell.java:43)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.fillRow(ExcelInput.java:138)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.getRowFromWorkbooks(ExcelInput.java:665)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.processRow(ExcelInput.java:471)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - Microsoft Excel Input.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - person - person
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - person - person
2018/10/05 21:04:32 - person - ERROR (version 5.0.0.1.19046, build 1 from 2013-09-11_13-51-13 by buildguy) : Errors detected!6

Error Executing transformation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your transformation involves an Input Excel step. This step is based on the Apache poi library.

1) Make sure your transformation is running in spoon.
2) Make sure the poi-.jar is on your java classpath.

You'll find the jar in the lib directory which was shipped wit your distribution. And to avoid that kind of surprises at a later stage, you may find useful to include all this lib on your classpath.

Comment: the transformation is running in spoon,and I also added all jars in classpath but still it is not working.

Comment: Check you do not have a conflict with Cell.getCellType()I defined twice.

Comment: for Cell.getCellType() ,I change the version of appache-poi ,now its working